# How to command ros_control joint commands other that publish to the /command topic of the joint

Tags: gazebo, ros-control, ros-noetic, ros-controllers

I'm using ROS Noetic, Gazebo 11.11

As the title states is there any other way to command the joints interfaced with ros_control in a gazebo simulation here in my case (effort_controllers/JointPositionController), (effort_controllers/JointVelocityController) other then the joint_controller/command topic.

And if I'm not wrong, I get the feedback of those joints in the /process_value topic? Right.

Need help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When using ros_control, you should typically use the `FollowJointTrajectory` action server provided by the `JointTrajectoryController`. FYI, this is what moveit will use to execute a plan.

I have no idea what the topic `/process_value` provides for you. That name is not standard for moveit. The more standard name is something like `/joint_states`.